# interstitial ad on button depended want to disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, buttonclick, interstitial

In this code there interstitial ad system is in button depended, which means if want to go next activity then you need must to the interstitial ad. After closing the ad then you can able to see the next activity. If you delete the ad code then you can not go to the next activity. so now I want to disable this to want to show interstitial ads but can not depend on any button. please solve this problem. My code is below,

```
package com.sheakdev.sscmath;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.mychat.MainActivity;
import com.example.mychat.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.krishna.fileloader.FileLoader;
import com.krishna.fileloader.listener.FileRequestListener;
import com.krishna.fileloader.pojo.FileResponse;
import com.krishna.fileloader.request.FileLoadRequest;
import com.sheakdev.sscmath.Model.Books;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import jp.wasabeef.glide.transformations.BlurTransformation;

import static com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions.bitmapTransform;


public class PdfDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int WRITE_EXT_STORAGECODE = 1;
    private static final int READ_EXT_STORAGECODE = 2;

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    FloatingActionButton favouriteBtn;
    FloatingActionButton downloadBtn;
    Button read;
    ImageView bookImageBack;
    TextView bookNameBack;
    TextView authorNameBack;
    TextView likesText;
    TextView readersText;
    TextView shareText;
    TextView bookCategory1;
    TextView downloads;
    TextView descriptionText;

    ArrayList<Books> dataListOffine;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    //Set<String> set;

    File file;
    String str;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView backgroundImage;
    String id = "";

    String bookName, authorName, bookImage, pdfUrl, description, downloadsstring, bookCategory = "";
    private Dialog progressDialog;
    private AdView mAdView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_detail);

        loadBannerAd();
        loadInterstatialAd();


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        ((ProgressDialog) progressDialog).setMessage("Please wait\nDownloading pdf...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);


        favouriteBtn = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        downloadBtn = findViewById(R.id.downloadBtn);
        bookImageBack = findViewById(R.id.bookImage);
        bookNameBack = findViewById(R.id.bookName);
        authorNameBack = findViewById(R.id.authorName);
        read = findViewById(R.id.readBtn);
        backgroundImage = findViewById(R.id.background_blur);
        likesText = findViewById(R.id.likesText);
        readersText = findViewById(R.id.readerText);
        shareText = findViewById(R.id.shareText);
        bookCategory1 = findViewById(R.id.bookCategory);
        downloads = findViewById(R.id.reviewText);
        descriptionText = findViewById(R.id.description);

        dataListOffine = new ArrayList<>();


        Intent i = getIntent();
        bookName = i.getStringExtra("bookName");
        authorName = i.getStringExtra("authorName");
        bookImage = i.getStringExtra("bookImage");
        pdfUrl = i.getStringExtra("pdfUrl");
        description = i.getStringExtra("description");
        bookCategory = i.getStringExtra("bookCategory");
        downloadsstring = i.getStringExtra("bookDownloads");

        descriptionText.setText(description);

        id = i.getStringExtra("id");

        Log.d("bookData:", "bookName " + bookName);
        Log.d("bookData:", "authorName " + authorName);
        Log.d("bookData:", "bookImage " + bookImage);
        Log.d("bookData:", "pdfUrl " + pdfUrl);
        Log.d("bookData:", "description " + description);
        Log.d("bookData:", "id " + id);

        /*final SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesDownloads = getSharedPreferences("downloads", MODE_PRIVATE);
        set = sharedPreferencesDownloads.getStringSet("key", null);

        try {
            dataListOffine = new ArrayList<String>(set);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        Log.d("idTest: ", "Id: " + id);

        sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("favourites", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean check = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("liked_" + id, false);

        if (check) {
            favouriteBtn.invalidate();
            favouriteBtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_filled));
        } else {
            favouriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up);
        }

        //setting selected book data
        //setting selected book data
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(bookImage)
                .into(bookImageBack);

        Glide.with(this).load(bookImage)
                .apply(bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(30)))
                .into(backgroundImage);

        bookNameBack.setText(bookName);
        authorNameBack.setText(authorName);
        bookCategory1.setText(bookCategory);

        try {

            downloads.setText(downloadsstring);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //for updating likes
        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books");
        final Query query = reference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot != null) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Books books = snapshot1.getValue(Books.class);
                        likesText.setText(books.getLiked());
                        if (snapshot1.child("readers").exists()) {
                            readersText.setText(books.getReaders());
                        } else {
                            readersText.setText("0");
                        }

                        if (snapshot1.child("shared").exists()) {
                            shareText.setText(books.getShared());
                        } else {
                            shareText.setText("0");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        favouriteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("favourites", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                boolean check = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("liked_" + id, false);

                if (check) {

                    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("favourites", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    editor.putBoolean("liked_" + id, false);
                    editor.commit();

                    final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books");
                    final Query query = reference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot != null) {
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    Books books = snapshot1.getValue(Books.class);
                                    String liked = books.getLiked();
                                    if (liked.equals("0")) {
                                        //do nothing
                                    } else {
                                        int integerLiked = (Integer.parseInt(liked)) - 1;
                                        books.setLiked(String.valueOf(integerLiked));
                                        reference.child(id).setValue(books);
                                        likesText.setText(books.getLiked());
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });


                    favouriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up);
                    Toast.makeText(PdfDetail.this, "Dislike", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    /*saveData(id);*/
                    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("favourites", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    editor.putBoolean("liked_" + id, true);
                    editor.commit();

                    final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books");
                    final Query query = reference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot != null) {
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    Books books = snapshot1.getValue(Books.class);
                                    String liked = books.getLiked();
                                    int integerLiked = (Integer.parseInt(liked)) + 1;
                                    books.setLiked(String.valueOf(integerLiked));
                                    reference.child(id).setValue(books);
                                    likesText.setText(books.getLiked());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });

                    favouriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_filled);
                    Toast.makeText(PdfDetail.this, "Liked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

        downloadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //storing value in array list
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        String[] permission = {
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        };
                        requestPermissions(permission, WRITE_EXT_STORAGECODE);
                        return;
                    }
                }


                bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) bookImageBack.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                progressDialog.show();

                savepdf();


                Log.d("bookDataf:", "bookName " + bookName);
                Log.d("bookDataf:", "authorName " + authorName);

                Log.d("bookDataf:", "pdfUrl " + pdfUrl);
                Log.d("bookDataf:", "description " + description);
                Log.d("bookDataf:", "id " + id);


                //dataListOffine.add(bk);
                //saveData();

                /*//Set the values
                set = new HashSet<String>();
                set.addAll(dataListOffine);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferencesDownloads.edit();
                editor.putStringSet("key", set);
                editor.commit();*/
            }

            private void savepdf() {

                FileLoader.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(pdfUrl, false) //2nd parameter is optioal, pass true to force load from network
                        .fromDirectory("test4", FileLoader.DIR_INTERNAL)
                        .asFile(new FileRequestListener<File>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLoad(FileLoadRequest request, FileResponse<File> response) {

                                saveimagetoGallary();


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(FileLoadRequest request, Throwable t) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                        connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                        return;
                    } else {
                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                    }
                } else {
                    // for offline oppening of book without ads...
                    final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books");
                    final Query query = reference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                            if (snapshot != null) {
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    Books books = snapshot1.getValue(Books.class);
                                    if (snapshot1.child("readers").exists()) {
                                        String readers = books.getReaders();
                                        int integerReader = (Integer.parseInt(readers)) + 1;
                                        books.setReaders(String.valueOf(integerReader));
                                        reference.child(id).setValue(books);
                                        readersText.setText(books.getReaders());
                                    } else {
                                        books.setReaders("1");
                                        reference.child(id).setValue(books);
                                        readersText.setText(books.getReaders());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });

                    Intent i = new Intent(PdfDetail.this, BookView.class);
                    i.putExtra("pdfUrl", pdfUrl);
                    i.putExtra("bookId", id);
                    i.putExtra("bookName", bookName);
                    startActivity(i);
                }


            }
        });
    }

    private void loadBannerAd() {
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }


    private void saveData(String id) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("favourites", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("liked_" + id, true);
        editor.commit();

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void saveimagetoGallary() {

        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis());
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(path + "/DCIM/.eBookImages");
        dir.mkdir();
        String imagename = time + ".JPEG";
        file = new File(dir, imagename);
        OutputStream out;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Booksdb bk = new Booksdb();
            bk.setBookName(bookName);
            bk.setAuthorName(authorName);
            bk.setBookImage(String.valueOf(file));
            bk.setPdfUrl(pdfUrl);
            bk.setDescription(description);
            bk.setId(id);

            MainActivity.myappdatabas.myDao().addBook(bk);
            progressDialog.dismiss();


            final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books").child(id);
            //final Query query = reference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    String dwnlds1 = snapshot.child("downloads").getValue(String.class);

                    Log.e("TAGFIRE", "onDataChange: " + snapshot + ":" + dwnlds1 + "id" + id);
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(dwnlds1);
                    val = val + 1;
                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("downloads", String.valueOf(val));
                    final int finalVal = val;
                    reference.updateChildren(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            downloads.setText("" + finalVal);
                            Toast.makeText(PdfDetail.this, "Download complete ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });


            // Toast.makeText(PdfDetail.this, "Saved in DCIM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    String[] permission = {
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    };
                    requestPermissions(permission, WRITE_EXT_STORAGECODE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveData() {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("saveData", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(dataListOffine);
        editor.putInt("dataListSize", dataListOffine.size());
        editor.putString("downloadBookData_" + id, json);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void loadInterstatialAd() {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9478755017139489/9139057379");
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {


                final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books");
                final Query query = reference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        if (snapshot != null) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                Books books = snapshot1.getValue(Books.class);
                                if (snapshot1.child("readers").exists()) {
                                    String readers = books.getReaders();
                                    int integerReader = (Integer.parseInt(readers)) + 1;
                                    books.setReaders(String.valueOf(integerReader));
                                    reference.child(id).setValue(books);
                                    readersText.setText(books.getReaders());
                                } else {
                                    books.setReaders("1");
                                    reference.child(id).setValue(books);
                                    readersText.setText(books.getReaders());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                Intent i = new Intent(PdfDetail.this, BookView.class);
                i.putExtra("pdfUrl", pdfUrl);
                i.putExtra("bookId", id);
                i.putExtra("bookName", bookName);
                startActivity(i);


                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                //isPlayed = true;
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        });
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your read button onClick code with this.

```
 read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                // for offline oppening of book without ads...
                final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books");
                final Query query = reference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        if (snapshot != null) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                Books books = snapshot1.getValue(Books.class);
                                if (snapshot1.child("readers").exists()) {
                                    String readers = books.getReaders();
                                    int integerReader = (Integer.parseInt(readers)) + 1;
                                    books.setReaders(String.valueOf(integerReader));
                                    reference.child(id).setValue(books);
                                    readersText.setText(books.getReaders());
                                } else {
                                    books.setReaders("1");
                                    reference.child(id).setValue(books);
                                    readersText.setText(books.getReaders());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                Intent i = new Intent(PdfDetail.this, BookView.class);
                i.putExtra("pdfUrl", pdfUrl);
                i.putExtra("bookId", id);
                i.putExtra("bookName", bookName);
                startActivity(i);
            }
    });
```

if you don't nead interstitial ad then comment this

```
//loadInterstatialAd();
```

Comment: bhai Asalamulaikum thank you very much for your reply. after replacing your code no ad is shown to my apps i tried it with admob test ad unit.